# Excel: Is there a simpler way to achieve this; numbers 1 - 20 in column A, 21-40 in column C, 41-60 in column E

Tags: excel

Is there a simpler way in excel to achieve this; numbers 1 - 20 in column A,  21-40 in column C, 41-60 in column E and so on.

```
A     B    C     D    E
1          6          11
2          7          12
3          8          13
4          9          14
5          10         15
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: What is the context? Are you doing this one time only for 20 rows? Is this meant to be a recurring function? Are you meaning to create it with formulas if not VBA?

Comment: a simpler way than what? Perhaps, place these formulas in `A1, C1, E1` respectively:  `=Row()`, `=Row()+5`, `=Row()+10`. Then drag down.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Do you want to populate numbers onto a blank spreadsheet? Or move numbers that are already there? For what purpose?

Comment: `=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=1,ROW()+((20*QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2))),"")` in A1 then copy down 20 rows and over as far as you want????

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. One of my colleagues showed me a snapshot of what a former staff did for her and asked me if I could replicate. The spreadsheet had numbers from 1 - 33 on the first column and then some random data for each of these numbers. Then the next number after 33 was in the column just immediately after the data. There were almost 15 columns of numbers. She wanted me to create this spreadsheet with these numbers and then her staff can manually enter the data. I asked where the original was so that I could see if there was any formula behind this, but she did not have it.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott Craner, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thank you nbayly, Scott Holtzman, Peter M and Scott Craner for your reply. I sincerely appreciate

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are doing, but this little subroutine will do what you need it to do... I think:

```
Sub makenumbers()
    Dim intCol As Integer, intRow As Integer, intCounter As Integer
    intCol = 1
    intCounter = 1
    For intCol = 1 To 40 Step 2
        For intRow = 1 To 20
            Sheet1.Cells(intRow, intCol).Value = intCounter
            intCounter = intCounter + 1
        Next intRow
    Next intCol
End Sub
```

Just change that `for intcol = 1 to 40 step 2` to whatever your last column is supposed to be.